# Array manipulation in java with empty limits

Tags: java, arrays

Can Someone help me in understanding how this code works

```
public class strManipulation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[][] = new int[3][];
        a[1] = new int[]{1,2,3};
        a[2] = new int[]{4,5};
        System.out.print(a[1][1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to find the answer somewhere here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works exactly how it looks like it works. `a` is type `int[][]` (an array of `int` arrays) and is assigned to a new array of 3 null `int[]`'s. Then `a[1]` (the second `int[]` in `a`) is assigned to a new array of 3 `int`'s containing some initial data. Then the second `int` of the second `int[]` in `a` is printed.

See the official language tutorial on arrays at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html.

Comment: +1 for `"It works exactly how it looks like it works."`

Answer (score 1):

Take it as a following 2-D matrix.

```
     |  0      1      2
_____|_____________________
     |
  0  | <------NULL----->
     |
  1  |  1      2      3
     |
  2  |  4      5
     |
```

Comment: user2207839----> this is the answer for your question! simple and visual aid too.

Answer (score 0):

You could print out the result like this:

```
public class StrManipulation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[][] = new int[3][];
        a[1] = new int[]{1,2,3};
        a[2] = new int[]{4,5};
        for (int m = 0; m < a.length; m++) {
            for (int n = 0; a[m] != null && n < a[m].length; n++) {
                System.out.println("Row:" + m + "; Column:" + n + "; Value:" + a[m][n]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Row:1; Column:0; Value:1
Row:1; Column:1; Value:2
Row:1; Column:2; Value:3
Row:2; Column:0; Value:4
Row:2; Column:1; Value:5
```

Explanation:

1 - You create a 2-Dimensional array, and specify that there are 3 rows.

2 - You leave the first row (index = 0) undefined.

3 - You populate the second row (index = 1) with 3 numbers, namely, 1, 2, 3.

4 - You populate the third row (index = 2) with 2 numbers, namely, 4, 5.

Comment: I do not believe `a[m] != null` is necessary.

Comment: @PM 77-1, the reason I keep it there is because it will throw Null Pointer Exception since the first row is not initialized (row = 0), you may confirm it yourself :-)

Comment: Yes, I was wrong. I mistakenly thought that 0 length will alone take care of the situation.